# EF Core: Code-first multiple relationships between classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not being able to map the relationships between below models:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<Product> _products = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Product>? Products => _products.ToList();
}
```

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category MainCategory { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Category> _relatedCategories = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Category>? RelatedCategories => _relatedCategories.ToList();
}
```

Rules:

- A product must belong to a category (called MainCategory): a one-to-many relatioship between category and product, where category is the principal
- A product may belong to many other categories (called RelatedCategories): has to be mapped as a many-to-many relationship between product and category

Important: I'm not allowed to change the models.

How would I do it without adding a second collection to the category model, for instance?

Can this even be achieved in EF Core? If so, how?

I'm using EF 7+.

Comment: Yes, all of this is supported.

Comment: @Candide How tho?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of EF? Many-to-many relationships are available in EF 7 and later. With earlier versions you basically modelled an association table as an entity.

Comment: Why is it bad modelling?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

in the `Product` model. You created the `MainCategoryId` but did not specify the corresponding Navigation Property in the `Category` model

```
 public class Category
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Product> _products = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Product>? Products => _products.ToList();

    private readonly List<Product> _mainProducts = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Product>? MainProducts => _mainProducts.ToList();
  }


public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MainCategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category MainCategory { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Category> _relatedCategories = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<Category>? RelatedCategories => _relatedCategories.ToList();
}
```

For more clarity, it is better to configure the entities relationship with FluentApi

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Products)
            .WithMany(e => e.RelatedCategories);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(x => x.MainCategory)
            .WithMany(x => x.MainProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MainCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you think there is a way to do it without adding a second product collection in the category model?

Comment: What problem does that second collection cause for you???? You are designing a relational database. But your design is wrong